# retain unique combinations from a list of tuples in python

Tags: python, combinations

I have a list of tuples that contain int and str values in them:

```
Listex:
[23,'item1','item2']
[23,'item2','item1']
[67,'item3','item2']
[55,'item3','item4']
[67,'item2','item3']
[55,'item4','item3']
```

What I need is to get unique tuples:

```
Listex output:
[23,'item1','item2']
[67,'item2','item3']
[55,'item3','item4']
```

I have tried sort() but I get the error that '<' cannot be used with str and int.
Appreciate any help in this regard.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you try `set()` ?

Comment: yes, doesn't work, I am guessing because of the different datatypes within the tuple

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all use [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) so that comparisons wont take into account the order of the strings, then use a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) to remove duplicates, finally convert back to list of lists:

```
In [1]: data = [[23,'item1','item2'], 
   ...: [23,'item2','item1'], 
   ...: [67,'item3','item2'], 
   ...: [55,'item3','item4'], 
   ...: [67,'item2','item3'], 
   ...: [55,'item4','item3']]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

In [2]: list(map(list, set(map(frozenset, data))))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Out[2]: [[67, 'item2', 'item3'], ['item1', 'item2', 23], ['item3', 'item4', 55]]
```

You cannot directly apply `set` to your original collection because `set` requires its elements to be *hashable*, which `list`s are not. Converting the inner lists into `frozenset` makes them hashable and has the added bonus of being order-independent. Using a `tuple` would make the elements hashable but order of the elements would matter.

Depending on what you want to do with the data maybe you can simply use a set of frozensets and avoid the lists altogether:

```
In [3]: set(map(frozenset, data))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Out[3]: 
{frozenset({67, 'item2', 'item3'}),
 frozenset({23, 'item1', 'item2'}),
 frozenset({55, 'item3', 'item4'})}
```

---

If you want to keep the number as the first element you can replace `list` with some function like:

```
In [5]: def keep_number_first(seq): 
   ...:     return sorted(seq, key=lambda x: 1 if not isinstance(x, (int, float)) else 0) 
   ...:
```

which sorts by type:

```
In [6]: list(map(keep_number_first, set(map(frozenset, data))))                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Out[6]: [[67, 'item2', 'item3'], [23, 'item1', 'item2'], [55, 'item3', 'item4']]
```

---

This said: if you have to keep data structured in this way, IMHO, it's probably better to come up with your own class or use a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) and give some meaning to the different pieces. For example instead of having `[23, 'item1', 'item2']` why not `(23, ['item1', 'item2'])`?

Comment: I am trying to extract nlargest also from this. Using frozenset, the distinct tuples are retained but I am not able to use it to get heapq.nlargest(). Any work around for that?

Comment: Thank you, using the keep_number_first worked. Any pointers for what the complexity of both operations together is? ie: using the sort in keep_number_first and map() and set() , added time complexity?

Comment: @savi It depends. `set` and `map` ecc are all linear time, so they shouldn't change the asymptotic complexity (although, obviously you still do more operations). The `sorted` call is O(n logn), *but* I assume that the elements of your list have a fixed or bounded size. If that's the case than it's O(1) (asymptotic complexity is only relevant if the input can grow indefinetly). Depending on how exactly your elements might be made you could replace `sorted` with a hand-made swap, but you should profile to see whether it's worth it.